# Python と Selenium で特定サイトでのクリックが無応答となり、タイムアウトとなる

Tags: python, selenium

ディズニー予約サイトに Python＋Selenium でボタンをクリックしていますが、応答が返却されません。

■対象ページ
https://reserve.tokyodisneyresort.jp/sp/hotel/search/

パソコンのブラウザではクリックして次に進んでいますが、Selenium で動かすと応答がなく、タイムアウトしています。
user-agentの設定を疑ったのですが、それを設定しても無応答のままです。

このサイトのように「Seleniumを使ったときだけ無応答となるサイト」は、対処方法がなく悩んでおります。

どなたか対処方法のお知恵を拝借できないでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import time

CHROMEDRIVER = "./chromedriver.exe"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://reserve.tokyodisneyresort.jp/sp/hotel/search/"

    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
    #ブラウザを起動
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER, options=options)

    agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
    print(agent)
    # urlにアクセス
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    try:
        # トップページを表示
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(1)

        # 「ホテルから」をクリック
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='ホテルから']" ).click()
        sleep(1)

        # 「ホテル」をクリック  ※レスポンスの返却なし、タイムアウト発生
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='東京ディズニーランド']" ).click()
        sleep(1)

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        #ブラウザ停止
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

対処としては chromedriver のオプションに `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` を追加します。これによって、`navigator.webdriver` が `false` に設定されます。(`true` の場合はブラウザが自動制御されていることを示しています) おそらく、TDL サイト側でこの値をチェックしているのかもしれません。

以下のコードを Python 3.11.6/Selenium 4.18.1 で実行しています。最新の Selenium では chromedriver のパスを指定する必要はなく、インストールされている Chrome のバージョンにマッチする chromedriver を自動的にダウンロードしてくれます。また、テスト目的で `detach` オプションを追加しています。

以下のコードですが、`"//*[text()='東京ディズニーランド']"` では `No Such Element` エラーが発生しますので、`"//a[contains(., '東京ディズニーランド')]"` に変更しています。

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='東京ディズニーランド']").click()
```

```py
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://reserve.tokyodisneyresort.jp/sp/hotel/search/"
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    #ブラウザを起動
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    # print(driver.execute_script('return navigator.webdriver'))

    # urlにアクセス
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    try:
        # トップページを表示
        driver.get(url)

        # 「ホテルから」をクリック
        link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='ホテルから']" )))
        link.click()

        # 「ホテル」をクリック
        link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., '東京ディズニーランド')]")))
        link.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        #ブラウザ停止
        # driver.quit()
        print('exit')
```

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、「chromedriver のオプションに --disable-blink-features=AutomationControlledを追加」することで、動作することができました。
また、稚拙なコードについても修正頂きありがとうございました。
数日悩んでも解決していなかったため、大変感謝致します。